# How to generate and load test data in amazon RDS for Oracle

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, benchmarking, tpc

For a POC, we need 10 GB of data to be available in Oracle RDS instance. Any test data is ok ( like TPC for benchmarking ) , for this requirement is there any specific way to create database and pump the sample data ?

Comment: Have you read [the AWS guidance on this topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/oracle-database/data-migration.html)?

Comment: How to upload oracle dump file to oracle database: AWS RDS
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548149/how-to-upload-oracle-dump-file-to-oracle-database-aws-rds/54551758#54551758

Comment: How to transfer Oracle dump file to AWS RDS instance?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378147/how-to-transfer-oracle-dump-file-to-aws-rds-instance/48378367#48378367

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have opened the firewall port 1521 to the RDS server, you should be able to use sqlplus, sqlci, sqlldr to connect to the RDS instance as follows:

`USER/PASSWORD@//hostName:port/SID`

e.g.

`sqlplus scott/tigerD@//myhost.this.that.amazon.com:1521/THE_SID`

Once you prove this works, use this in the tools to squirt data into the RDS instance.

E.g. .sql INSERT scripts, sqlldr scripts etc.